# Defining global variables to hold values that will be referenced by a raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a text based RPG.  With that bit of context, let's say I wanted to make a global list of spells, and then define certain actions for those spells to take when called upon by a user.  So if I have a global list of spells, what is the best way to assign certain actions for those spells to have?  This is a bit of code that will help you somewhat understand my combat mechanics.  I need to allow the user to call upon 'heal', for example, and then have heal hold the properties of raising health numbers and a cool down mechanic, e.g. "You must wait 5s to use this spell again." What's the best way to define those properties, and have those properties be global, so they can be referenced through each combat function without having to reiterate the properties?

Here is a portion of my code that may clear up my combat mechanics.  When the player is prompted under raw_input 'inp' to type the name of the spell, and they type heal, a cool down effect should apply for a certain length of time, or perhaps a certain number of turns in combat, as well as the ability to raise user life.  The property I use for life is under a class called 'user' and a variable 'health'.  So `user.health = 100` is valid

```
available_spells = ['heal', 'fireball']
equipped = {'Armor': 'Mage Robes',
          'Weapon': 'Wooden Staff',
          'Spells': ['heal', 'fireball']

print "Your available spell(s) is(are) '%s'. " % equipped["Spells"]
inp = raw_input("Type the name of a spell you want to use.: ").lower()
lst = [x for x in available_spells if x.startswith(inp)]
if len(lst) == 0:
    print "No such spell"
    print ' '
elif len(lst) == 1:
    spell = lst[0]
    print "You picked", spell
    #combat functions here
else:
    print "Which spell of", equipped["Spells"], "do you mean?"
```

Comment: Seems like you already know about dictionaries, why not use them for the spells?

Comment: Okay, by how do I use a cooldown?  How could I code that?